# How to install current OpenPYXL package on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apt-get, openpyxl

I have some spreadsheet reading code (using openpyxl) that works correctly on my Windows installation.  On my Ubuntu Rackspace server, however, it fails with a named range error.

I notice that the openpyxl package on Ubuntu (which I installed last week using apt-get) is several years old (1.5.6).  I'd like to install the newest version (1.6.2).

What tool can I use to install the newer version, or is it something I need to do manually?

Comment: It looks like it's on the Python Package Index: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl, so you should be able to do `sudo pip install openpyxl`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (after using apt-get to install pip).  Please post as an answer so that I can mark it correct and other people can find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python packages available in the Ubuntu repositories generally don't get updated within an Ubuntu version, only when you upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release.

When you need newer versions of a Python package, you can use `pip` to get the newest version from the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi):

```
sudo pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: hmm it answered me `ImportError: No module named _internal
`

Answer (score 6):

Stuck on the same problem, this is what I did to fix it.

On linux machines you need to install via apt package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-openpyxl python3-openpyxl
```